# React onClick changes Paginated data one step Behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Writing a simple frontend pagination, with a next and a back button. When I console.log(state) may state seems to be changing according to my plan when clicking the buttons. However the webpage displays the state data from one page back.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useStateValue } from "../state";
import getChar from "../api/index";
import Spinner from "../components/loading"

export default function Characters(props) {
  // access state and dispatch functions here
  const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  let [page, setPage] = useState(1);


  const apiCall = async (num) => {
    const first = (4 * num) - 4;
    const last = (4 * num) - 1;
    const res = await getChar.getCharacters();
    const display = res.results.filter((char, index) => {
      return (index >= first && index <= last);
    })
    await dispatch({
      type: 'GET_CHARACTERS',
      data: display
    });
    setLoading(false)
    setIndex(res.results.length)
  }

  // move to next page
  const next = () => {
    const newPage = page + 1;
    const maxPages = Math.ceil(index / 4);
    if (newPage > maxPages) {
      setPage(maxPages)
      apiCall(maxPages)
    } else {
      setPage(newPage)
      apiCall(newPage)
    }
  }

  // move back a page
  const back = () => {
    const newPage = page - 1;
    if (newPage === 0) {
      setPage(1)
      apiCall(1)
    } else {
      setPage(newPage)
      apiCall(newPage)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall(1)
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div><Spinner /></div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Characters Page</h1>
      {
        state.characters.map((char, index)=> (
          (char.starships.length === 0) ?
            <div className="List" key={index}>
                <h3 className="character">
                  {char.name}
                </h3>
            </div>
          :
            <div className="List" key={index}>
                <h3 className="character">
                  {char.name} - pilot
                </h3>
            </div>
        ))
      }
    <button onClick={back}>back</button>
    <button onClick={next}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function reducer(state, action) { 
  switch (action.type) { 
    case "GET_CHARACTERS": 
      state.characters = action.data;
      return state; default: return state; 
  } 
}
```

Shows the previous states data before click until the last page in the pagination. Will not show the last bit of paginated data until click the back button viceversa for the first bit of data.

Comment: What did the reducer named GET_CHARACTERS do? Can you show the code of the reducer?

Comment: Yeah for sure, here's the reducer.

```
export default function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_CHARACTERS":
      state.characters = action.data;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The react can't detect a change in a mutable object. A new state object should be returned in every reducer.

```
case "GET_CHARACTERS": 
    state.characters = action.data;
    return {...state};
```

or

```
case "GET_CHARACTERS": 
    return {...state, characters: action.data};
```

Some useful information:

- This is a note on state and setState in the react documentation. [using-state-correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)
- This is mentioned in the introduction of the useState of the react, how does the react compare the two states before and after. [Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)
- This is what was mentioned when redux introduced the reducer. [We don't mutate the state.](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions)

this is a demo of mutable object.

```js
var a= {name:1}
var b = a;
b.name=2
var result = Object.is(a,b)
console.log(result) // true
```

Comment: Thanks!! Just tried the first suggestion and it works. I will have to read up on react and mutable objects. If your have a suggestion where to start please share a link.

Still trying to wrap my head around why spreading the state in an object solved my problem.

Comment: @kidCaulfield I added some links and example to the answer and hope to be helpful.